# Read chunk with jszip

Tags: node.js, jszip, adm-zip

I couldn't find a way to read zip content as a chunk from HTTP response.

I provide an example with JSZip library .(I'm open to other libraries if necessary )

```
const zip = new JSZip();

const readZipCunk = async (chunk)=>{
     const ziped = await zip.loadAsync(chunk, { optimizedBinaryString: true })
     ziped.forEach((relativePath, file) => {
            file.nodeStream().pipe(parser); // parser is not relevant , just demonstrate 
                                           //what i do with the "extracted" chunk
     });
}

https.get(options, (res) => {
     res.on("data",readZipCunk );
 })
```

When the zip file is small it could success but when the filesize is large im getting error.
Error: Corrupted zip: can't find the end of central directory

ofc, if i will concat chunks and invoke "readZipCunk " function in the:

```
response.on('data',(chunk)=>{chunks.push(chunk})
response.on('end',()=>{readZipCunk( Buffer.concat(chunks)}) // it will work
```

But i must keep the memory low as I can, also I know some information on the zip file like the file name , size  , maybe I can use this information and avoid using of request the central directory?